# Identify overlapping configurations in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm setting up a configuration excel sheet to be imported into a database.

It has four columns

```
Equipment  Fleet    Start Date     End Date    Highlight Me
=============================================
  A          X       1-Jan-20       5-Jan-20       X
  A          Y       6-Jan-20       
  B          C       1-Jan-20       3-Jan-20
  B          D       4-Jan-20      10-Jan-20
  A          Z       3-Jan-20                      X
  A          Z                      5-Jan-20       X
```

I need to identify and highlight overlapping configs

I'd like lines 1, 5 and 6 to be highlighted.

- They are all a configuration for the same *Equipment*, but their configuration dates overlap
- *Fleet* is that attribute we are configuring for the date range but has no bearing on the validation

Constraints:

- I'd like to use tables (not named ranges) for this. My table is called `tblFleetConfig`
- Yes I could do this in VBA but I don't want to deal with trusted workbooks etc. etc.

So far I have pasted this into a column on the right

```
=
(tblFleetConfig[@[Start Date]] >= tblFleetConfig[Start Date]) 
* 
(tblFleetConfig[@[Start Date]] <= tblFleetConfig[End Date]) 
* 
(tblFleetConfig[@Equipment]=tblFleetConfig[Equipment])
```

The result I'm getting is a 1 for the first line and 0 for every other line.

Clearly I don't understand this syntax and I'm interested in learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked a complicated one, those blanks throw a wrench into it.

Your formula is the right syntax, you need to wrap it in a SUMPRODUCT() though.

`=SUMPRODUCT((tblFleetConfig[End Date]<=tblFleetConfig[@[End Date]])*(tblFleetConfig[Start Date]>=tblFleetConfig[@[Start Date]])*(tblFleetConfig[Equipment]=tblFleetConfig[@Equipment]))`

This is your formula wrapped it in a SUMPRODUCT().

This will return a 1 if there is a single occurrence and a number greater than 1 if multiple.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry I'm not back fully engaged on this right now so my troubleshooting brain capacity is limited. When I paste that in I get _The Syntax of this name isn't correct_. When I put `tblFleetConfig` in front of everything it works but: 1. I have to drag the formula down - it doesn't automatically align with the table (maybe that's not an issue) 2. Every row is 1 anyway. I'll come back to this at some point and do further troubleshooting. I suspect that when I use `SUMPRODUCT`, it lose some table capability but I also suspect it may be the only solution

Comment: You need the SUMPRODUCT() or Excel will only evaluate against the single row, not the whole table. 

I apologize, I thought the formula was part of the table, with it outside the table you do need to add the table name.

I dropped the blank cell check, try it this way: `=SUMPRODUCT((Tablefleetconfig[End Date]<=Tablefleetconfig[@[End Date]])*(Tablefleetconfig[Start Date]>=Tablefleetconfig[@[Start Date]])*(Tablefleetconfig[Equipment]=Tablefleetconfig[@Equipment]))`

Comment: The SUMPRODUCT is necessary to force Excel to evaluate each cell as a range, your other option is an array formula. 

What table capability are you worried about losing?

Comment: My understanding is that when I add records to table it will automatically extend the "named range" whereas a named range won't. I also like the formatting. I didn't realise I could put a formula in a table. I've now moved the expression in there (and taken out `tblFleet`)

Comment: So right now if I paste the formula in I get a 1 for everything and a 2 if there's an overlap. Which is wierd because the individual terms all return zero. I don't know why there are ones but this is sufficient for me to do conditional formatting

Comment: ..actualy it seems I can't do conditional formatting based on this formula, I have to put it in a cell

Comment: If I put this into a conditional formula into the "Format Values where this syntax is true" field, I get "The syntax of this name isn't correct" `=IF(SUMPRODUCT([End Date]<=[@[End Date]])*([Start Date]>=[@[Start Date]])*([Equipment]=[@Equipment])>1,TRUE,FALSE)`